# how to set value on attributes of input using codeigniter php

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a function `insert_blog` in admin controller when no `id` pass in url then I want to show a blog form where I set a value from (like: `set_value('blog_title')`) `form_validation` false occur .

I have a list of blogs where I click edit button on particular blog I call `insert_blog` function again with `id` like `register/insert_blog/1001` .

At this item I call model class where I get list of details for this particular blog and i want to set this value to input.

**My controller code:**

```
public function insert_blog($id = NULL)
{
    if($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
    {
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('title','Blog Title','trim|required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('date', 'Date', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('description','Blog Description','trim|required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('blog_content', 'Blog Content', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
   // $this->form_validation->set_rules('upload','Blog Upload Image','trim|required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('written', 'Blog Written By', 'trim|required|xss_clean');

    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    { 
        $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
        $data['blog_id'] = $id;
        $data['this_blog'] = $this->admin_model->getBlog($id);
        $this->load->view('admin/new_blog',$data);   
    }else{
        $this->load->model('admin_model');
        $result = $this->admin_model->insertBlog();
        redirect('admin/blog_list');
    }
    }else{
        redirect('/admin/login');
    }
}
```

**My view code:**

```
<?php 
$data = array('name'=>'title',
'class'=>'form-control',
'id'=>'title',
'placeholder'=>'Blog Title',
'value'=>set_value('title', $this_blog->blog_title));  

echo form_input($data);
?>
```

Comment: A bit of code indentation would not go amiss in this code

Comment: what does `var_dump($this_blog->blog_title);` gives?

Answer (score 0):

do this:

```
$data = array(
          'name'        => 'username',
          'id'          => 'username',
          'value'       => 'johndoe',
          'maxlength'   => '100',
          'size'        => '50',
          'style'       => 'width:50%'
        );

echo form_input($data);
```

as explained on https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html